# LSF wget not working with bsub

Tags: download, wget, lsf

I am trying to run a script on a server through their lsf system for submitting jobs.  When I run wget without using bsub, wget successfully downloads the file I'm looking to get.  However, when I run the identical command inside of bsub, the job runs, but wget gets stuck no matter how long I allow the job to run (it should only take about 10 sec to download the file).   Here are the commands I've run:

```
wget ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov/1000genomes/ftp/data/NA19238/sequence_read/ERR000018.filt.fastq.gz #This one runs no problems.

bsub -q short -J wgettest -oo wtest.out -eo wtest.err wget ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov/1000genomes/ftp/data/NA19238/sequence_read/ERR000018.filt.fastq.gz #This one does not work. :(
```

The stderr file for the job is as follows

--2012-07-05 20:57:59--  ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov/1000genomes/ftp/data/NA192
38/sequence_read/ERR000018.filt.fastq.gz
           => `ERR000018.filt.fastq.gz'
Resolving ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov... 130.14.250.10
Connecting to ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov|130.14.250.10|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... 
Login incorrect.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The complete server seems to be down at the moment... so I cannot try, but what happens if you submit the job directly from one of the compute nodes? Is this possible?

Comment: Try with wget -d.  Post the output.

Answer (score 1):

In a beowulf cluster it is standard practice for the worker nodes to be cut off from the outside network. Your job is being run on a worker node when you submit with bsub so it will not have internet access. This is why your connections to the cluster must always be made through one of the head nodes. In general you should download any needed files manually on the head node (without bsub) before submitting a job.  If you must be able to download something from the worker node some sort of tunneling may be possible, but you'll have to talk to your cluster admin about that.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that the machine on which the command got executed did not have an Internet access.

The commands are run on the nodes post the allocation of the resources.

Check if you have a proxy that you can couple with the system and then perform the wget through that.